# Apparent F#/BCL floating point bug

Tags: .net, f#, base-class-library

The following is in FSI:

```
> System.Math.Round(0.2916, 2);;
val it : float = 0.29
> it * 100.;;
val it : float = 29.0
> int it;;
val it : int = 28
```

The result is the same everywhere I tried - a compiled F# 3.1/.NET 4.0 application, FSI in Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, .NET Fiddle, @fsibot....

Surely this is a bug somewhere, isn't it? What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just how floating point numbers work. The number that appears as 29 in the output is actually slightly smaller than 29 (because floating point numbers are not precise):

```
> (System.Math.Round(0.2916, 2) * 100.0) - 29.0;;
val it : float = -3.552713679e-15
```

Comment: Okay, I did suspect it might have to do with that, but the output in FSI fooled me into thinking the value was exactly `29.0`.

Comment: It's worth adding here that it's very easy to get burned by loss of precision when reading/writing floats to disk as strings.  .NET supports round-trip formatting of floats so the bits converted to human-readable chars and parsed back to bits will yield exactly the same bits.  See the Round Trip ("R") Format Specifier, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

`float` is binary floating point data type. Not all decimal floating point values can be represented exactly as binary floating point. What FSI shows as `29` is actually `28.999999999999996`.

If you want to store precise decimal floating point values, use `decimal` data type (to make a number literal `decimal` instead of `float` add `m` to it - e.g. `0.2916m`).

```
> System.Math.Round(0.2916m, 2);;
val it : decimal = 0.29M
> it * 100m;;
val it : decimal = 29.00M
> int it;;
val it : int = 29
```

Answer (score 5):

You can change the F# FSI Pretty Printer like Matlab "format long"

```
fsi.AddPrinter( fun (x:float) -> sprintf "%26.16e" x);;
```

FSI output

```
System.Math.Round( 0.2916, 2)   //  2.8999999999999998e-001

1./3.                           // 3.3333333333333331e-001
```